# How to set Maximum value on anchor tag?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, e-commerce

On my cart page I want to update product quantity. It is working but I want, when the product quantity reach the maximum value (same as quantity on product table) it throw an error message.

**my blade view:**

```
<form action="#" method="POST">
    <div class="plus-minus">
        <a class="dec qtybutton" href="javascript:void (0)" onclick="CartDecrementQuantity('{{$cart->id}}')">-</a>
        <input type="text" value="{{$cart->product_quantity}}" name="qtybutton" class="plus-minus-box" readonly>
        <a class="inc qtybutton" href="javascript:void (0)" onclick="CartIncrementQuantity('{{$cart->id}}')">+</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

I am not using input tag that's why i made it readonly'

**Route:** Ajax route to increase cart quantity.

```
Route::post('increase_quantity',['as' => 'increase_quantity', 'uses' => 'User\UserController@increase_quantity']);
Route::post('decrement_quantity',['as' => 'decrement_quantity', 'uses' => 'User\UserController@decrement_quantity']);
```

**Controller:**

```
public function increase_quantity(Request $request)
{
    $cart = Cart::with('product')->find($request->cart_id) ;
    if ($cart->product_quantity < $cart->product->quantity) {
        $cart->increment('product_quantity');
    }
    $unit_price=$cart->product_quantity*$cart->product->sellPrice;
    $per_product_quantity=$cart->product_quantity;
    $cart_quantity=Cart::with('product')->get();
    $total_price = 0;
    foreach ($cart_quantity as $cart) {
        $total_price += $cart->product_quantity*$cart->product->sellPrice;
    }
    return response()->json([
        //'cart_quantity' => $cart_quantity,
        'total_price'=>$total_price,
        'unit_price'=>$unit_price,
        'id'=>$request->cart_id,
        'product_quantity'=>$per_product_quantity
    ]);
}
public function decrement_quantity(Request $request)
{
    $cart = Cart::with('product')->find($request->cart_id) ;
    if ($cart->product_quantity >1) {
        $cart->decrement('product_quantity');
    }
    $unit_price=$cart->product_quantity*$cart->product->sellPrice;
    $per_product_quantity=$cart->product_quantity;
    $cart_quantity=Cart::with('product')->get();
    $total_price = 0;
    foreach ($cart_quantity as $cart) {
        $total_price += $cart->product_quantity*$cart->product->sellPrice;
    }
    return response()->json([
        //'cart_quantity' => $cart_quantity,
        'total_price'=>$total_price,
        'unit_price'=>$unit_price,
        'id'=>$request->cart_id,
        'product_quantity'=>$per_product_quantity
    ]);
}
```

**Ajax Code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function CartIncrementQuantity(id){
var cart_id = id;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "{{ route('increase_quantity') }}",
            data: {
                _token: '{{csrf_token()}}',
                cart_id: cart_id,
            },
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response['product_quantity']);
                $('#product_price'+response['id']).text(response['unit_price']);

                $('#menubar_product_quantity'+response['id']).text(response['product_quantity']);

                $('#unit_price'+response['id']).text(response['unit_price']);
                $('#menubar_total').text(response['total_price']);
                $('#menubar_total1').text(response['total_price']);
                $('#subtotal').text(response['total_price']);
            },
            error:function (response) {
            }
        });
    }

function CartDecrementQuantity(id){
    var cart_id = id;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "{{ route('decrement_quantity') }}",
        data: {
            _token: '{{csrf_token()}}',
            cart_id: cart_id
        },
        success: function (response) {
            $('#product_price'+response['id']).text(response['unit_price']);
            $('#menubar_product_quantity'+response['id']).text(response['product_quantity']);
            $('#unit_price'+response['id']).text(response['unit_price']);
            $('#menubar_total').text(response['total_price']);
            $('#menubar_total1').text(response['total_price']);
            $('#subtotal').text(response['total_price']);
        },
        error:function (response) {
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.
Here iam using early return pattern.
You can read more about it [here](https://medium.com/swlh/return-early-pattern-3d18a41bba8).

```
public function increase_quantity(Request $request)
{
    $cart = Cart::with('product')->find($request->cart_id) ;
    // If we reached the limit, we can throw Exception, or return JsonResponse with error message
    if ($cart->product_quantity === $cart->product->quantity) {
        return new JsonResponse(['error' => ['message' => 'Your error message']], 422);
        // Or throw new \Exception('Your error message', 422);
    }
    // All code below will work only if $cart->product_quantity < $cart->product->quantity
    $cart->increment('product_quantity');
    $unit_price=$cart->product_quantity*$cart->product->sellPrice;
    $per_product_quantity=$cart->product_quantity;
    $cart_quantity=Cart::with('product')->get();
    $total_price = 0;
    foreach ($cart_quantity as $cart) {
        $total_price += $cart->product_quantity*$cart->product->sellPrice;
    }

    return new JsonResponse([
        //'cart_quantity' => $cart_quantity,
        'total_price'=>$total_price,
        'unit_price'=>$unit_price,
        'id'=>$request->cart_id,
        'product_quantity'=>$per_product_quantity
    ], 201);
}
```

Comment: App\Http\Controllers\User\JsonResponse not found

Comment: You need to use it on the top
use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;

Comment: You need to handle error, in you front-end code.

Comment: I know but also error message not showing on my console

Comment: what prints `console.log(response);` inside
`error:function (response) {}`